# Formula Results being transformed as values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my spreadsheet, I have both input from an external api and calculations from other sheets.

From Columns A:H, the data is being constantly refreshed through the following script:

```
  var pull_url = 'https://';         //ommited
  var get_options = '';              //ommited

  var pull_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pull_url, get_options);  
  var pull_csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(pull_response);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("InputSheet");

  var range = sheet.getRange("A:H");
  range.clear();

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, pull_csvData.length, pull_csvData[0].length).setValues(pull_csvData);
```

From columns range "I:W", I have a bunch of formulas that needs to be calculated everytime I run the script. 
However, everytime I run my script the formulas are being replaced as values.

Could you guys advise me on how to avoid the formulas to be transformed into values or even how to make them be calculated for every row/column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that `pull_csvData[0].length` returns a value big enough to overwrite the formulas on columns I:W. You should insert more columns or to replace it by the column number of column H, 8.